# React Navigation - Dynamic Height of Container

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I am trying to achieve a bottom sheet for a mobile app, with a navigation.

I am using `react-native-bottom-sheet` and `react-navigation` v6.

The `react-native-bottom-sheet` works fine with dynamic height, however the issue i have is with `react-navigation`.

TL;DR;

Is it possible to have the `NavigationContainer` have a dynamic height?I have tried a onLayout on the screens, however if the screen is changing it doesn't call the onLayout, which makes it not dynamic o the content.
Is it something that us possible to achieve? That the navigation container be dynamic height?